# Vue3: Los componentes solo se muestran cuando la extensión Vue Devtools está abierta

Tags: vue.js, vue3

Estoy trabajando con una aplicación Vue sencilla en un único archivo Javascript.
La aplicación funciona, **el problema es que los componentes no se muestran**, y no tengo errores ni advertencias. Solo se muestran cuando inspeciono la aplicación mediante la extensión **Vue Devtools** para chrome.

```javascript
const app = Vue.createApp({...})

app.component('my-component-name', {
  template: `<input type="text" name="test">`
})

app.mount("#app");
```

También lo intenté de esta manera:

```javascript
const App = {
  components: {
    'my-component-name': {
      template: `<input type="text" name="test">`
  }
  data() {
    ...
  }
}

const app = Vue.createApp(App).mount("#app");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La segunda forma está bien, nada más te falta la coma

```
const App = {
  components: {
    'my-component-name': {
      template: `<input type="text" name="test">`
    }
  },
  data() {
      return {}
  }
}

const app = Vue.createApp(App).mount("#app");
```

Finalmente asegurate de llamar el componente desde `#app`

```
<div id="app" class="demo">
  <my-component-name />
</div>
```

Revisando la primera también está bien

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
   components: {
    'my-component-name': {
      template: `<input type="text" name="test">`
    }
  },
  data() {
       return {}
  }
})

app.component('my-component-name', {
  template: `<input type="text" name="test">`
})

app.mount("#app");
```

> Ambos códigos probados en codepen funcionan. Asumo que tu error es que no estás llamando el componente desde `#app`, ya que si te faltara la coma recibirías algún error.  https://codepen.io/team/Vue/pen/KKpRVvJ

Comment: Confirmo que el problema se debió a un **v-if** del elemento padre, cuya condición dependía del valor de una función que logicamente se llamaba solo al inicio de la aplicación. He cambiado la condición a una propiedad calculada. Gracias.